# Android 11 onCreate() call is missing every second time

Tags: android, lifecycle, blocked

A mature app suddenly poses a lifecycle problem never seen before, when running on Android 11:

- start debugguing
- onCreate() is called
- onStart() is called
- onResume() is called
- app is running
- user finishes app
- onStop() is called
- user taps on app icon
- onDestroy() is called
- onCreate() is called
- onStart() is called
- onResume() is called
- app is running
- user finishes app
- onStop() is called
- user taps on app icon
- empty window pops up, nothing is called, app is blocked

This happens every second time the user starts the app. I have no idea why this happens - when the user taps on the app icon, I would expect Android to always call either onCreate() or onStart(). Any idea?

Comment: What about `onResume()`?

Comment: Is there any service running within the app? Any resources that may not be cleared and/or reinitialized properly after those "restarts" ?

Comment: I added the onResume() calls above.

Comment: There are no services running and no uncleared resources.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I set a breakpoint at super.onDestroy() and not at the start of onDestroy(). As this function was not getting ready in the second run and never called super.onDestroy(), the last onCreate() never happened.